# How to center the checkbox tick-mark in the Ant Design Checkbox component?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

You can see the tick mark in the image below, and it is slightly aligned to the bottom-right. I want to center it. How can I achieve this?

[image: Antd checkbox image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where do you see it misaligned? their check seems to be thicker